# How do you replace a line with forward slashes in it in EX?

Tags: vim

I'm running a script for  vim EX mode I've tried every escape character and word identifier I can find. 
 it needs to find the string "/etc/walker" and replace it with "/etc/runner"

```
% s/\</etc/walker\>/\</etc/runner\>/g
wq
```

same issue with a script to append at the end of the file. It doesn't do anything. I'm trying to append "/etc/walker"

```
$
a
\</etc/walker\>
.
wq
```

what I've tried on regex editors seems to work there but not in EX

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
:s#/etc/walker#/etc/runner#
```

Notice the use of `#` as a delimiter, that way you don't have to add back slashes.

You could also use:

```
:s@/etc/walker@/etc/runner@
```

For appending at the end of the line:

```
:s#$#/etc/walker#
```

In EX mode just remove the `:` at the beginning.

Comment: That works! I tried it with @ but my main script wasn't calling correctly so I though it was failing. O.o my bad. Thank you.

Do you know why the append script doesn't work?

Comment: Hi, Just update the answer with an example of how to append at the end of the line, hope it helps

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for that. I just avoided EX for the append and used echo. Thank you for the help.